# FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: on visual studio code

Tags: python

It works on python but on visual studio code python it does not work.

```
from os import startfile
vid = "‪‪C:\\Users\\l1v37\\Pictures\\tenor.png"
startfile(vid)
```

```
PS C:\Users\l1v37> & C:/Users/l1v37/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39/python.exe c:/Users/l1v37/Documents/idkthismaywork.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\l1v37\Documents\idkthismaywork.py", line 5, in <module>
    startfile(vid)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified: '\u202a\u202aC:\\Users\\l1v37\\Pictures\\tenor.png'
```

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Use a raw string: `vid = r"‪‪C:\Users..."`

Comment: That doesnt work

Comment: Show us exactly what you tried and what the result was! "doesn't work" is not an acceptable error description on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Your file name string (`vid`) has 2 invisible Unicode LTR characters ([202A](https://unicode-table.com/en/202A/)) embedded at the beginning (in front of the drive specifier). You see them in the error message as `\u202a`. Remove them as they certainly don't belong to your file name.

Comment: It's more the `vid` variable value that contains extra char at the beginning, then the filename per-se.

Comment: @zigarn: yes, technically a file name could contain such characters, but not in the positiion before the drive specifier, I assume.

Comment: That works, but not on the normal python, it works on visual studio code

Comment: If your problem is still not solved, you need to give more information. For example, you gave us 3 lines of code, but the error message sais the problem is in line 5. That does not match. Make the problem a [mre] and we can help you. Honestly, I can hardly believe that it works in VS Code if you use the exact same file. I do believe however, that it may work if you copy paste the code, because the LTR characters might get lost during the copy-paste operation. You start Python 3.9 via Powershell. What version of Python does VS Code start? So many questions ...

Answer (score 0):

Your string value contains 2 unicode values at the start of the string. This is normally from when you copy/paste something from a webpage into your code that contains hidden/zero width/non-visible characters.

From this [unicode identifier](https://babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html), we can see the value of all characters in the string.

Using the string `"‪‪C:\\Users\\l1v37\\Pictures\\tenor.png"` (copy/pasted directly from your question), here is the output of the first several characters.

```
U+202A : LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING [LRE]
U+202A : LEFT-TO-RIGHT EMBEDDING [LRE]
U+0043 : LATIN CAPITAL LETTER C
U+003A : COLON
U+005C : REVERSE SOLIDUS {backslash}
```

Retype the string and your issue will be solved.

Comment: Can you specify what "doesn't work" means? Is it performing the same action? have you tried recreating the problem in a fresh environment?